# Symfony 2 routing pattern lenght {1,}

Tags: symfony, routes

i could not find a answer to my question.
I have this kind of route. 
    `pattern:  /foo/{dir}/{dir1}/{ficname}`
I would like to know if un could do something like

```
pattern: /foo/{dir}/{ficname}
    requirements:
        dir:  ([a-zA-Z]+/?)+
```

EDIT: In my case .+ was too much permisive and  finaly ([a-zA-Z]+/?)+ wasn't enought.

Final solution (i choose):

> ```
> pattern: /foo/{dir}/{ficname}
>     requirements:
>         dir:  ([^/]+)||([^/]+/[^/]+)+
> ```

**Correction**

> ```
> pattern: /foo/{dir}/{ficname}
>     requirements:
>         dir:  [^/]+(/[^/])*
> ```

I have got a problem with the old solution when they where more than 2 '/' because the second passage cant find any charactere else '/' and was + then could not work

Comment: you can use `.+` regex, so `dir:  .+`

Comment: It work perfectly  thank you very  much ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.+` regex: `dir: .+`.

See [this cookbook article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/slash_in_parameter.html).

Answer (score 1):

I added this route:

```
dirs-filename:
    path: /foo/{dirs}/{filename}
    requirements:
        dirs: ([a-zA-Z]+/?)+
```

When I check:

```
bin/console router:match /foo/dir/file            # OK
bin/console router:match /foo/dir/subdir/file     # OK
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: you  are currently using Symfony 3 not 2 but still working ( next maybe you should check tag  ^^)

Comment: The only difference is the app/console vs bin/console, no ? The routing component is the same.

Comment: I'm not sure but i think as you (i working on SF3 project too  and i didnt see any kind off différence on routing component between SF2 and SF3)